# How do I unlock Bitlocker compect laptop drive (d) in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, bitlocker

I am using Windows 7 compact laptop cq40, one I lock d drive through bitlocker, but now I forgot my password, how can I unlock my drive d without restoring or formatting my d drive datas.

Comment: That's why you regularly create backups. To still have your data in case something goes wrong with your laptop, like it being stolen, the hard disk failing, or user incompetence.

Answer (score 6):

You can't unless you made a key recovery disk. That's the whole point of Bitlocker.